# Change style of chapter

Tags: titlesec

I want to customize my chapter titles using \ usepackage [avantgarde] {quotchap} style which I find beautiful but I want to change the alignment of my titles and for that I use:

```
\ makeatletter
\ patchcmd {\ @ makechapterhead}
  {\ raggedleft \ advance}
  {\ raggedright \ advance}
  {} {}
\ makeatother
```

and I still want to add the word chapter before the chapter number as shown in the following image:

[image]

here is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[avantgarde]{quotchap}


\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\newpage
\appendix
\chapter{Definition}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's not very clear – in the image,  ‘Chapter’ is below the chapter number, not before;

Comment: I try to put the chapter before or below

Comment: It can easily be done using `titlesec`.

Comment: how to use titlesec, titleformat ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how to do it, as far as I understand the layout you want. Note I replace `avant-garde` with its `tex-gyre-adventor` clone:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{apptools}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\LARGE\bfseries}{\filleft\fontfamily{qag}\selectfont%
\IfAppendix{\appendixname}{\chaptername}\,\scalebox{4}{\color{lightgray}\thechapter}}{1ex}{}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum
\newpage
\appendix
\chapter{Definition}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I have beat the downvoter on math.se :-)....I not like the haters grrr :-)))

Comment: Thank you very much @Bernard.